# Find the ID of a folder - Content Type is Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud

How can I find the ID of a folder from the interface. The content type is Data Extension.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

From [Email Studio > Email > Subscribers > Data Extensions], assuming your browser's status bar is enabled, hover over the folder and wait for the URL to fully expand (either a `CategoryID` query parameter or a `categoryId` JS object property is what you're looking for)...

[image]

Alternatively, from [Contact Builder > Data Extensions], right-click the folder then "inspect" the element in the browser's dev tools...

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I can find the id of a folder which is used for emails. I am looking to find the id of a folder which is storing the data extensions. If you create a folder under the parent folder named Data Extension, how can you find the id of that child folder?

Comment: @MonomitBhowmik The screenshots I posted in my answer are from an actual child folder under the parent Data Extension folder (i.e., it's the same process you follow for email objects; `Email Studio > Email > Subscribers > Data Extensions`).